# substr inside php echo

Tags: php, substr

In my code below `substr` function is not working, why it is so and how to make it work.

```
<?php
// some code

echo "
<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>
<p> substr( ".$row['body'].",0,300) ....</p>
<p>".$row['posted']."</p>";
```

Comment: Because its not treated as a function instead its been simply a string over here take care about string concatenation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my code below `substr` function is not working, why it is so?

- Its because its been treated as string literal and not a function

> How to make it work?

- You need to take care about string concatenation or simply store the value of `substr` within a variable.

Example:

```
$substr_value = substr($row['body'],0,300);
echo "
<h2>{$row['title']}</h2>
<p>$substr_value</p>
<p>{$row['posted']}</p>";
```

Answer (score 5):

Correct code should be like this:

```
echo "
<h2>". $row['title'] ."</h2>
<p> ". substr($row['body'],0,300) ." ....</p>
<p>". $row['posted'] ."</p>";
```

> Because `substr($row['body'],0,300)` is php syntax you you need to
>   separate it.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "
<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>
<p>" . substr($row['body'],0,300) . " ....</p>
<p>".$row['posted']."</p>";
```

You didn't correctly format it, the substr cannot be inside quotes.